# Rails 3 - create multiple records using javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an array with some parameters dynamically generated in Javascript. After filling some fields and pressing submit I want to generate multiple records in DB which contains data from form field + data from the array i.e. name,array[0];name,array[1];name,array[2] etc.. So I've decided to do following:
in my view (I use simpleform)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@stop_time, :html => {:remote => true, :class => 'well form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :stop_id %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

and the script part (I use fixed values for now):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#new_stop_time').submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        'X-CSRF-Token', 
        $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
    url: "/stop_times.json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify([
      arrival_time:"04:40:00",
      created_at:"2013-04-20T20:37:30Z",
      departure_time:"04:40:00",
      drop_off_type:0,
      id:1881,
      pickup_type:0,
      shape_dist_traveled:null,
      stop_headsign:null,
      stop_id:84612,
      stop_sequence:1,
      trip_id:"ABCDE",
      updated_at:"2013-04-20T20:37:30Z"
    ]
    ]})
  });
});
```

but in chrome debug I see 2 POST requests being sent (one /stoptimes from form and other /stop_times.json wich got response with code 422).

Shouldn't be just one POST request? I want Javascript to do POST not the form.
Is there any other (more obvious) way to create multiple records?

Thanks,

Dominik

Thanks @UberNeet:) Now it works with one record. It passes to the controller and the correct record is created. I can create the whole array to pass it  as JSON but not sure how to handle it on controller's side. I assume there's some loop needed but I don't know how the params is build.I've added following:

```
@i = 0 
while @i< params.length-1 do
  @stop_time = StopTime.new(params[@i][:stop_time])
  @i +=1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The form is posting two times, because you are marking the form as `:remote => true` and adding your custom AJAX post.

When you mark the form as `:remote => true`, the Rails unobstrusive javascript library kicks in and adds an event handler to the form. (More Info @ "Working with Javascript in Rails"[http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html] Note that this is for Rails 4)

Don't mark the form as `:remote => true`, and inside your custom function for the ajax, make sure you return false for the submit.

```
$('#new_stop_time').submit(function () {
  $.ajax({ ... });
  return false;
});
```

Returning false will cancel the regular form submission.

If you want to create multiple records using AJAX, you need to pass the array of items in your Ajax method and the controller action must also support handling that data. Think of your Rails action as an API.